# windows script for building multimodule maven project

Tags: windows, console, maven, batch-file

I'm trying to create a .bat file for automatic building of a multimodule maven project, the script is :

```
mvn clean install
cd ./webapp
mvn jetty:run-war
```

However, the first line seem to close the console window, so I never get to the last line. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
call mvn clean install
cd ./webapp
call mvn jetty:run-war
```